# Python: How to store data in class and inherit

Tags: python-3.x, class

I am pretty new to classes and I already wrote a class for doing some Pandas operations.

However I noticed, that working with objects can result in objects that don't know the original definitions. So I came to **@classmethod**, but I don't have an idea of how to use them.

**Goal of my class:**
I want to write a Permission class. It should load/write a json-file and one should be able to add more permissions.

**EDIT:**
After some reading I ended up with a `staticmethod` and a `__init__` that load the file during their initialization.

```
class Permission:
    data = None

    def __init__(self, path):
        if Permission.data is None:
            self.read_permissions(path)

    @staticmethod
    def read_permissions(path):
        try:
            with open(path, 'r') as read_file:
                Permission.data = json.load(read_file)
        except FileNotFoundError as e:
            logging.error(e)
            sys.exit(1)

    def add_permissions(self, group, level, permissions):
        self.data['groups'].append({
            'group': group,
            'level': level,
            'permissions': permissions
        })
```

So I can use the class like this:

```
json_path = 'C:\\data\\test.json'
test_perm = Permission(json_path)

print(test_perm.data)
{'groups': [{'group': 'common', 'permissions': {'select_sample_x': True, 'select_sample_y': True, 'assign_x': False, 'request_y': True}}]}

test_perm.add_permissions('guys', 10, {'can_do_icecream': False, 'can_do_nothing': True})

print(test_perm.data)
{'groups': [{'group': 'pkf_common', 'permissions': {'select_sample_debitor': True, 'select_sample_creditor': True, 'assign_third_party_confirmation': False, 'request_reporting': True}}, {'group': 'guys', 'level': 10, 'permissions': {'can_do_icecream': False, 'can_do_nothing': True}}]}
```

Comment: Shouldn't 'read_permissions' return a 'Permissions: object?

Comment: How are you calling your code?

Comment: @rassar: Yes you are right, the code didn't show a good working example. I altered the code with feedback of doctorlove

Comment: @doctorlove: Do you think that cls can be used in my code, like you did in `with open(cls(path).path, 'r') as read_file:`?

Comment: Looking back, I haven't typed what I mean - I'll fix that

Answer (score 1):

Since most of your methods are `@classmethod`, you might find it easy to just use functions.

You can read permissions, and maybe let the calling code decide what to do on an error:

```
def read_permissions(path):
        with open(path, 'r') as read_file:
            return json.load(read_file)
```

Previously, you returned `cls(path).data` so the calling code would have to keep hold of the `data`.

Once you have one set of permissions, called `data` returned from this, you can use your `add_permissions` to append to `data['groups']`, without using classes at all.

An alternative is to load some data when you make a class instance, and use that instance from then one:

```
class Permissions:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        self.data = []
        try:
            with open(path, 'r') as read_file:
                self.data = json.load(read_file) #<--- store in instance
        except FileNotFoundError as e:
            logging.error(e)
            sys.exit(1) #slightly extreme, but up to you

    def write_permissions(self, filename): #note the new filename
        with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(self.data, outfile, indent=4)

    def add_permissions(self, path, group, permissions):
        self.data['groups'].append({
            'group': group,
            'level': 0,
            'permissions': permissions
            }) #now in the instance
```

You can then use your class:

```
path_json = r'C:\data\file.json' #raw string
data = Permissions(path_json) #this now reads when you make the class instance
data.add_permissions(json_path, 'guys', {'can_do_icecream': False, 'can_do_nothing': True})
data.write_permissions(r'C:\data\new_file.json') #raw string
```